# Entity Framework Created a DB that is a newer version than What is Readable By Visual Studio Server Explorer. How can this be fixed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I used EntityFramework to generate a database for a few models in Asp.NET MVC. However, I can't look inside this database via visual studio server explorer. This is the error I get: "The database {x} cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 and earlier."

How can I set up Visual Studio to work with the generated database?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the express edition? There may be limitations

Comment: I am running visual studio ultimate 2013 with all updates installed. I dont have a separate SQL server install.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to (localdb)\mssqllocaldb ?

Comment: Are you referring to defaultconnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are having the same problem, I can provide my solution.

I have not been able to figure out how to make entity framework itself generate a database compatible with server explorer.

However, using the default database specified in the original config should do the trick. I wouldn't be able to tell you why in the world that is, though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kory for providing solution.

I've been doing WingTip Toys ASP.NET tutorial and I encountered the same problem.

In my case it turned out I just mixed up names

When you create your child class of DbContext you can provide ConnectionString in base constructor

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext()
        : base("WingtipToys2")
    {
    }
    //...
}
```

This ConnectionString name must be the same as in your Web.config file:

```
<add 
 name="WingtipToys2" 
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

After providing correct names, deleting and recreating database file (it was mandatory in my case), new database opens in server explorer.

Hope that helps,

Charles

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the App_Data folder. There should be an `*.mdf` file that contains your database. Inside Server Explorer, click "Connect to Database" and point it to this file. I don't see why that will not work.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do.